# Getting the value out of a dynamic asp:DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

Basically, I have a drop down list with a ID and runat="server" tag and is inside a asp:TableCell. The original DDL has no options, but through javascript, I am populating the dropdown with some options that update my table on the front end. On button click, through my vb.net code, I need to retrieve the text inside the ddl. Any suggestions of how to do this would be nice. Thank you in advance, and if you need any more information from me please let me know.

P.S. I am not able to use ajax with this project.

[HTML] - Just showing the tablecell and ddl

```
<asp:TableCell ID="ocProduct">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="myDropDown"  CssClass="ocProduct" 
      OnChange="indexChanged(this);" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:TableCell>
```

[VB.net]

```
Protected Sub updateWeight_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  msgbox(myDropDown.text) ' does not work
  msgbox(mytable.rows(1).cells(0).text) ' does not work
  msgbox(myTable.rows(1).cells(0).controls(0).toString) ' does not work
  msgbox(myDrowDown.selectedValue) ' does not work
  ' All of these are returning "" 
end sub
```

[JavaScript] - This is just showing how I load the ddl

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('myDropDown');
var tempOption = document.createElement('option');
tempOption.text = "Please select an option..."
tempOption.value = 0;
ddl.options.add(tempOption);

for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    var tempArray = parsePerHash(i); 

    option.text = tempArray[0];
    option.value = i;

    ddl.options.add(option);   
    }
};
```

Comment: it's because you populate ddl by js and try to get value(s) from backend... after you click on button, page is reloaded and you'll lose all values, controls and so on created/added by client side... try adding hidden field `<input type="hidden" id="ddlselect" runat="server" value="" />`, on ddl option change store selected value in that, for example, `ddlselect` and then get value from vb. update: so you don't need server side ddl control, but simple `select`.

Comment: You sir deserve a gold medal. I have spent two weeks trying to get ajax, jquery, and other frameworks to work with my application and this was the best advice I have ever come across. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad... post Your solution like an answer and mark it, so someone else can see solution.

Comment: I've rollbacked your last edit: please find your solution in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51747710/revisions) and post it as an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the specific properties of that control.
Try using "msgbox(myDropDown.SelectedValue)". You can see the list of properties here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This still returned me a string "" instead of the actual value inside of the ddl.

Comment: It's possible that the value is not posting back to the server. Try adding AutoPostBack="true" to your dropdownlist  and see if that helps at all.

Comment: since the table is being displayed by front end javascript, when a postback occurs on index changed in the ddl, the entire table is erased, including the ddl values.